# Sql Server performance on select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a question about the performance of a query.

I have a table named tblHistory and it contains 17'000 rows.
I have a table named tblItem with 14'000 rows and a table tblItemType with about 10 rows which are in relation like described below in query.

The following query shows 0sec in managment Studio:

```
Select tblItem_Id, tblItem_Title, 
CountHistoryItems = 
(
SELECT count(*) FROM tblHistory 
where tblHistory_ItemId = tblItem_Id 
)
from tblItem INNER JOIN tblItemType ON tblItem_ItemTypeId = tblItemType_Id
```

The following query Shows 0sec in Management Studio:

```
Select tblItem_Id, tblItem_Title
from tblItem INNER JOIN tblItemType ON tblItem_ItemTypeId = tblItemType_Id 
where 
(  
    tblItemType_BaseTypeId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000200' or  
    tblItemType_BaseTypeId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000300'
)
```

As soon as I use both examples together like the following query it needs about 2 minutes in managament Studio for getting the result:

```
Select tblItem_Id, tblItem_Title,
CountHistoryItems = 
(
SELECT count(*) FROM tblHistory 
where tblHistory_ItemId = tblItem_Id 
)
from tblItem INNER JOIN tblItemType ON tblItem_ItemTypeId = tblItemType_Id
where 
(  
    tblItemType_BaseTypeId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000200' or  
    tblItemType_BaseTypeId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000300'
)
```

Do you have any idea why this takes so Long or could you tell me how I can make it faster?

Thank you very much.

Best regards.
Ivan

Comment: Which indices do you have on your tables?

Comment: The way you debug such issues is by looking at the execution plan. Post it here.

Comment: did you have a look at the executionplan to see what part of your query takes the most time?

Comment: It shows the following in execution plan: Select 0%, Compute Scalar 0%, Nested Loops 0%, Hash Match 1%, Indes Seek (nonclustered) 0%, Clustered Index Scan (clustered) PK_tblItem 48%, Compute Scalar 0%, Stream Aggregate 0%, Clustered Index Scan (clustered) PK_tblHistory 50%. What does this say? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
select 
    tblItem_id
    ,   tblItem_Title
    ,   count(*) as CountHistoryItems
from
    tblItem 
    inner join tblItemType on tblItem_ItemTypeId = tblItemType_id
    inner join tblHistory on tblItem_id = tblHistory_itemId
group by tblItem_id, tblItem_title
where 
(  
    tblItemType_BaseTypeId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000200' or  
    tblItemType_BaseTypeId = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000300'
)
```

Also rebuild your indexes if necessary (PK_tblItem and PK_tblHistory)

Answer (score 0):

create a non clustered index on `tblItemType_BaseTypeId` if you have not

Comment: I made a non clustered index but it does not make any difference. Any other idea?